# How to extract a particular value from an INI File using a Regular Expression?

Tags: .net, vb.net, regex, silverlight

I am a bit confused how to best use a Regular Expression and hope I can get some help I want to extract a URL value from an INI File as such:

```
[DEFAULT]
BASEURL=http://www.stackoverflow.com/
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://www.stackoverflow.com/
```

So I can get the URL value as the only Match from the Regular expression - but I don't understand enough about them (yet) to do this.
I have seen RegEx examples that will parse any INI file and get the Name, Value Pairs I just want to get the URL value only from a file no matter what else it contains.
My aim is to have something like this:

```
Dim _pattern As New Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("RegEx")
Dim _url As String = _pattern.Match(iniContentString).Value
```

It seems simple but I cannot seem to create a specific case RegEx where I want everything from "URL=" to the vbCrLf at the End to be my "Match".
I have refered to Regular-Expressions.info which has been a help before but still cannot get this simple example to work.

Comment: Dumb question, but is there a reason you're not using "GetPrivateProfileString"? This does exactly what you're trying to do http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724353(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Also, what actual regex expression are you using? i.e. what appears where you have "Regex" in Regex("RegEx")

Comment: And doesn't exist in Silverlight

Comment: @RoguePlanetoid: Maybe you should add a silverlight tag? It's important information that narrows your solution space.

Comment: I did - when I double clicked on the last Tag it must have replaced it, as it was the first - did not notice - will amend, thanks!

Comment: The "RegEx" was where the magic was to go - my RegEx was a mess so thought I'd exclude it. Not sure if it would help if I'd left it there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
New Regex("^URL=(.*)$", RegexOptions.Multiline).Match(iniContent).Groups[1].Value
```

Note that this will match *any* `URL=` line, whatever section it's in.
If that's not what you want, please tell me.

**EDIT**: It should actually be `.Groups[`**`1`**`].Value`; this will not include `URL=`.

Comment: This is more like what I needed, I'd only ever used them for characters not whole strings. This does work but I still get the "URL=" part - could this be excluded, otherwise I'll use a String Replace to get rid of it and mark as answer.

Comment: Thanks for the Edit, the URL and Match are two seperate groups - I always wondered if there was a "returned" part of a RegEx. Did not know that, this now works!

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression below matches value on a line after parameterName and equal sign.
All spaces and tabs outside parameterName and value are ignored.
Space followed by a semi-colon begins in-line comment.

```cs
var parameterName = "URL";

var regex = new Regex(
    pattern: $@"^[ \t]*{parameterName}[ \t]*=(?:(?:[ \t]+;.*)|(?:[ \t]*(\S.*?)(?:(?: ;.*)|(?:[ \t]+))?))$",
    RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var value = regex.Match(_iniContent).Groups[1].Value;
```