# Read value from ini file with 'File.ReadAllText'

Tags: c#, ini

I have some `ini` file include this string : `_DeviceName = #1234`.  Now I want to get the `_DeviceName` value that is `1234` but it shows me the full string that is `_DeviceName = #1234`.
I tried this code:

```
if (File.Exists("inifile.ini"))
{
    if (File.ReadAllText("inifile.ini").Split('\r', '\n').First(st => st.StartsWith("_DeviceName")) != null)
    {
        string s = File.ReadAllText("inifile.ini").Split('\r', '\n').First(st => st.StartsWith("_DeviceName"));

        MessageBox.Show(s);

    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling `ReadAllText` twice and splitting. Looks like you'd be better off calling `File.ReadAllLines` once.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading/writing an INI file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217902/reading-writing-an-ini-file)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to extract a particular value from an INI File using a Regular Expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946686/how-to-extract-a-particular-value-from-an-ini-file-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: If possible, you should use an INI library, or upgrade to the XML conf files that .Net and most modern frameworks strongly encourage.

Answer (score 2):

You could add another split to get the value out:

```
if (File.Exists("inifile.ini"))
{
    if (File.ReadAllText("inifile.ini").Split('\r', '\n').First(st => st.StartsWith("_DeviceName")) != null)
    {
        string s = File.ReadAllText("inifile.ini")
                   .Split('\r', '\n').First(st => st.StartsWith("_DeviceName"))
                   .Split('=')[1];
        MessageBox.Show(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: You might also `Trim()` it to eliminate the inevitable leading whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) instead. You may want to look at existing `ini` file readers if you're doing anything more complex but this should work. As a side note, it's not efficient to make two `File.ReadAllText` calls so quickly; in most cases it's best to just store the result in a variable).

```
if (File.Exists("inifile.ini"))
{
   string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines("inifile.ini");
   string deviceLine = allLines.Where(st => st.StartsWith("_DeviceName")).FirstOrDefault();

   if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(deviceLine))
   {
      string value = deviceLine.Split('=')[1].Trim();
      MessageBox.Show(value);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an application that implements an INI Reader/Writer.  Source code not available just yet, but keep checking back, I will have the source uploaded in a few days ( today is 8/14/13) .  This particular INI Reader is CASE SENSITIVE and may need modification for special characters, but so far I have had no problems.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/dungeonchest/

Answer (score -1):

A dirty way would be to use **String.Replace("_DeviceName = #", "")**

Comment: I think you mean `s = s.Replace("_DeviceName = #", String.Empty);`...but your point is valid regardless.

Comment: Yes just used String as a generic term